# Finding/creating candidate key(s) in a data frame

Tags: r, key

I am looking for a way to determine the candidate keys in a `data.frame`.

For a simple example, if I have a `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), Col2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2))
```

Then clearly Col1 or Col2 are not keys that individually uniquely identifies each row, but the concatenation of `Col1+Col2` would be.

Finding a single column that could serve as a key could be found by comparing `length(unique(df$column)) == nrow(df)`.

But if my `data.frame` contains many columns and no single column is a key, then possibly the concatenation of two columns together might be.

The question is, how can I find out which two will do the trick? Which three? etc. I realize this could be an exponentially growing exhaustive search but I wonder if there is a better way.

I have written code to at least search through all possible 2-column combinations but it is extremely cumbersome.

Comment: I'm not clear why 1) you wouldnt know or at least have an idea which columns to combine for keys and 2) why not just use 1:nrow(df)

Comment: or just concatenate all identifier type fields and hash

Comment: rawr: This situation actually comes up frequently in data prep. I am given two or more datatables from a client that I need to join but the names are not quite the same since they are from two different systems, and they are not always 1st normal so in order to join and not get duplication of rows I need to find out what combination of fields makes a unique row key. For example, CustomerNumber+OrderNumber ? or Customer+OrderNumber+OrderDate ?

Comment: Hi A. Webb: The problem is I don't know all the identifier fields as some numerical fields could actually be identifier codes not numbers. I'd like to find the smallest subset, and all possible candidate concatenations in order to try to match up and join with another datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's not entirely clear to me what motivates finding a key in this way, I suppose it could be interesting in identifying what combinations of characteristics uniquely identify individuals in a population.

As you point out, an exhaustive search could be very expensive, since there are `2^k` possible subsets of `k` variables that you would need to check. Still, it is easy to code and provides a benchmark for runtimes:

```
all.keys <- function(dat) {
  combos <- tail(expand.grid(sapply(dat, function(x) c(F, T), simplify=FALSE)), -1)
  nunique <- unlist(apply(combos, 1, function(x) nrow(unique(dat[,x,drop=FALSE]))))
  combos[nunique == nrow(dat),]
}
```

For the 11-column `mtcars` dataset, this runs in about half a second and returns 1,276 different combinations of columns that could be used as keys; no single column can be used as a key but there are 9 pairs of columns that could be used.

```
dim(all.keys(mtcars))
# [1] 1276   11
head(all.keys(mtcars))
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat   wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
# 34 TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 36 TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 38 TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 40 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 42 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 44 TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
table(rowSums(all.keys(mtcars)))
#   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11 
#   9  52 148 266 322 266 148  53  11   1
```

For a dataset with many columns, it's probably hopeless to try to compute all possible keys efficiently, since the number of valid keys likely grows exponentially in the number of variables. We may have a chance of efficiently finding the smallest possible key size (in this case keys of size 2). One straightforward approach would be looping through key sizes and stopping once we find a valid key of that size:

```
small.keys <- function(dat) {
  for (size in 1:ncol(dat)) {
    keys <- combn(names(dat), size)
    nunique <- apply(keys, 2, function(x) nrow(unique(dat[,x,drop=FALSE])))
    if (sum(nunique == nrow(dat)) > 0) {
      return(t(keys[,nunique == nrow(dat)]))
    }
  }
  return(NULL)
}
```

This runs in under 10 milliseconds on my computer (50x faster than the exhaustive approach for mtcars) and returns the 9 keys of size 2:

```
small.keys(mtcars)
#       [,1]   [,2]  
#  [1,] "mpg"  "wt"  
#  [2,] "mpg"  "qsec"
#  [3,] "cyl"  "qsec"
#  [4,] "disp" "qsec"
#  [5,] "hp"   "qsec"
#  [6,] "drat" "qsec"
#  [7,] "wt"   "qsec"
#  [8,] "qsec" "am"  
#  [9,] "qsec" "carb"
```

Of course, this will still perform badly if the only valid keys are large or if there are no valid keys, since we still need to exhaustively check through all subsets of variables in that case.

Comment: This works!! Thank you. Of course this will depend on the values in the columns how much it has to search, but I tested this on a small dataset = 10,500 rows by 75 columns and it ran in 30 sec and found 3 solutions I had not previously found. I have an Intel i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz.

Since I need to only run this utility when I initially work with data, I can wait 30 sec or a few minutes to get this valuable information. Again, thanks.